Finding a Minimum Translation Distance
I have been trying to implement a version of separating axis theorem using the snippet posted below. Currently, there is no minimum translation distance supplied with the snippet, and I am unable to work out where to find one.
#include <iostream>

// define the operations to be used in our 3D vertices
struct vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
    vec3 operator- (const vec3 & rhs) const { return{ x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y, z - rhs.z }; }
    float operator* (const vec3 & rhs) const { return{ x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y + z * rhs.z }; } // DOT PRODUCT
    vec3 operator^ (const vec3 & rhs) const { return{ y * rhs.z - z * rhs.y, z * rhs.x - x * rhs.z, x * rhs.y - y * rhs.x }; } // CROSS PRODUCT
    vec3 operator* (const float& rhs)const { return vec3{ x * rhs, y * rhs, z * rhs }; }
};

// set the relevant elements of our oriented bounding box
struct OBB
{
    vec3 Pos, AxisX, AxisY, AxisZ, Half_size;
};

// check if there's a separating plane in between the selected axes
bool getSeparatingPlane(const vec3& RPos, const vec3& Plane, const OBB& box1, const OBB&box2)
{
    return (fabs(RPos*Plane) > 
        (fabs((box1.AxisX*box1.Half_size.x)*Plane) +
        fabs((box1.AxisY*box1.Half_size.y)*Plane) +
        fabs((box1.AxisZ*box1.Half_size.z)*Plane) +
        fabs((box2.AxisX*box2.Half_size.x)*Plane) + 
        fabs((box2.AxisY*box2.Half_size.y)*Plane) +
        fabs((box2.AxisZ*box2.Half_size.z)*Plane)));
}

// test for separating planes in all 15 axes
bool getCollision(const OBB& box1, const OBB&box2)
{
    static vec3 RPos;
    RPos = box2.Pos - box1.Pos;

    return !(getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisX, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisY, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisZ, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box2.AxisX, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box2.AxisY, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box2.AxisZ, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisX^box2.AxisX, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisX^box2.AxisY, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisX^box2.AxisZ, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisY^box2.AxisX, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisY^box2.AxisY, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisY^box2.AxisZ, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisZ^box2.AxisX, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisZ^box2.AxisY, box1, box2) ||
        getSeparatingPlane(RPos, box1.AxisZ^box2.AxisZ, box1, box2));
}

// a quick test to see the code working
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // create two obbs
    OBB A, B;

    // set the first obb's properties
    A.Pos = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f }; // set its center position

    // set the half size
    A.Half_size.x = 10.f; 
    A.Half_size.y = 1.f; 
    A.Half_size.z = 1.f;

    // set the axes orientation
    A.AxisX = { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f };
    A.AxisY = { 0.f, 1.f, 0.f };
    A.AxisZ = { 0.f, 0.f, 1.f };

    // set the second obb's properties
    B.Pos = { 20.f, 0.f, 0.f }; // set its center position

    // set the half size
    B.Half_size.x = 10.f;
    B.Half_size.y = 1.f;
    B.Half_size.z = 1.f;

    // set the axes orientation
    B.AxisX = { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f };
    B.AxisY = { 0.f, 1.f, 0.f };
    B.AxisZ = { 0.f, 0.f, 1.f };

    // run the code and get the result as a message
    if (getCollision(A, B)) std::cout << "Collision!!!" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "No collision." << std::endl;

    // pause and quit
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

I have tried to separate the results gained from the getSeparatingPlane function into minimum and maximum values, like other posts suggest. It isn't clear where to make the separation.
